# What is special about printf over echo

Tags: echo, tcsh, hp-ux, printf

I was finding length of a variable as below:

```
`set num=123456`
`echo $num|wc -c`
```

it returned output as 7 (suppose to return 6)

I did same with `printf`

```
`printf "%s" $num|wc -c`
```

it returned output as 6 ( as expected)

Does `echo` considering null character while counting? 
is `Printf` counting till null character?

what is so special about `printf`?

Comment: The echo is also printing a newline, printf is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to see this is to use something like `od -c` which prints all characters:

```
$ echo 123456 | od -c
0000000   1   2   3   4   5   6  \n
0000007
$ printf 123456 | od -c
0000000   1   2   3   4   5   6
0000006
```

As you can see, `echo` prints an extra `\n` but `printf` doesn't. `wc -c` counts bytes, it doesn't care whether the character in question can be seen by humans or not, it just counts the number of bytes in its input.

As for what's so special about `printf` vs `echo`, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222) for more details than you ever wanted to know.

Comment: If  `bash` did not introduce an incompatible behavior with `echo` around 1990, `echo` would be usable...but `bash` introduced `echo -e` that is not covered by POSIX (only `echo -n` triggers unspecified behavior).